# Explain Maven artifact differences: kafka-client, kafka_2.11-<kafkserver-version>, scalatest-embedded-kafka_2.11.

Tags: scala, kafka-consumer-api

Please explain the maven artifact differences and when to use what? for kafka-client, kafka_2.11-, scalatest-embedded-kafka_2.11. Is anything specially used for writing unit tests?

I want to understand when to use what?
In my repo, we have been using kafka_2.9.2-0.8.1.1, currently we are planning to move to kafka broker 0.9.0.1. Hence I used kafka_2.11-0.9.0.1 and also tried kafka_2.10-0.9.0.1.
When the unit tests runs, kafkaTestServer (kafkaserverstartable) always hangs internittently with kafka_2.10 and kafka_2.11
but with kafka_2.9.2-0.8.1.1 - never had hang issue.

if it proceeds, it failed with KafkaConfig init error or ScalaObject not found error.

I m kind of confused about these artifacts? Can anyone explain me about this?

Answer (score 1):

The names encode the use Scala version as well as the uses Kafka version. For example `kafka_2.9.2-0.8.1.1` is for Kafka `0.8.1.1` (ie, the suffix after the `-` is the Kafka version number and the binaries got compiled using Scala `2.9.2`.

Thus, if you write code, you want to use the same Scala version as you artifact was compiled with. I assume, that the hanging and error is due to Scala version mismatch.

Comment: I did use the right scala version. I made sure to check every dependencies. But still was getting into issue. I will reverify again,

Comment: It might help if you share your pom.xml and error message (only relevant parts).